# Change the text of the cell delete button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm trying to change the delete button of a cell. 
I have 2 functions :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let titleBtn = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "Supprimer") { (action , indexPath ) -> Void in
        self.isEditing = false
    //ackAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    }
    return [titleBtn]
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

But, when I run my app, the text of the button is changed but the delete doesn't work (i can't delete data from my array and the row of my tableview). Before to add this functions all  worked perfectly.
A detail: in the `canEditRowAt` function, I tried to return false too...
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 6):

if you want to change the text of the delete button, conform this method in the `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String?
{
     return "Your new title"
}
```

To delete the item from the array conform this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) 
    {
        yourDataSourceArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        yourTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, all is ok now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can either use default delete action and change its title like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String?
    {
        return "MyAction"
    }
```

or you can create your own action buttons like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") {action in
            //handle delete
        }

        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") {action in
            //handle edit
        }

        return [deleteAction, editAction]
    }
```

Comment: When `UITableViewRowAction` was added in iOS 8, they didn't clarify that there were two ways to create a delete button in a row... hence two ways set the title:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowaction/1614993-title